# Start div from end of wrapped text

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create the effect seen in the following picture.

[Ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwreu.jpg)

So, I have some text on the left, with a max-width of 50% (could be anything really), some short text on the right and dotted line in the middle of them.

The question is: is it possible for me to make the dotted line extend up to where the wrapped text ends?

Normally the dotted line will end at the right-most point of the left-side text but that's quite undesirable.

I am working with Sass and NextJS (not that I expect it to matter, but you never know maybe there's an npm module I haven't heard of just for this) and this is what my current Sass looks like (with only the code that matters, I took out font stuff).

```css
.outerDiv{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    align-self: stretch;
}

.text{
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 50%;
}

.dashedLine { /* This is just a div with border */
    height: 1px;
    flex: 1;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted black;
    margin: 0 4px 0 4px;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

(Also feel free to let me know if I have bad tags or formatting on this, I'm new to asking questions.)

Comment: your css is almost there.. put a `flex-basis: 50%` on that sucker(.text) and make sure you have `flex-grow: 1`, `flex-shrink;1` and `flex-wrap` set. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those dots are called `leaders` and there are multiple ways to achieve them using `css`. E.g. UIKit library has a leader implementation (see [here](https://getuikit.com/docs/leader)).
There is a W3C working draft (version of [2 August 2019](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#typedef-leader-type)) that includes a `leader()` function for css.

There is a whole article about dot leaders on the W3C website (see [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html)) too. This example is taken from there:

```html
<ul class=leaders>
  <li>
    <span>Salmon Ravioli</span>
    <span>7.95</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Bruschetta</span>
    <span>5.25</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Margherita Pizza</span>
    <span>10.95</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul.leaders {
    max-width: 40em;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.leaders li:before {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    content:
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . "
 ". . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ";
}
ul.leaders span:first-child {
    padding-right: 0.33em;
    background: white;
}
ul.leaders span + span {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0.33em;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

This isn't exactly what I was looking to do but it is absolutely close enough. I also explored some other solutions thanks to the newfound knowledge of the dots being called leaders but nothing really fit my use case as well as this.

Thanks again! Have a nice day :]